# While loop requesting JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to do something that I thought was pretty simple but now I'm pretty sure that I've well and truly over-simplified it or just messed up something basic with my loop. I'm trying to search through a list of links that contain JSON objects to find specific ones that contain specific data.

The JSON links I'm looking through look like this:

Link 1:

```
{"genre": "fantasy", "title": "Book 1"}
```

Link 2:

```
{"genre": "scifi", "title": "Book 2"}
```

And the goal of my loop is to find a book with the genre 'scifi', however my current code just causes or nothing to happen. If anyone can spot what I've done wrong, please let me know. In case it wasn't obvious I'm pretty new at this so any suggestions would be very welcome.

```
function find_book(){ // called by button onclick
    var i = curr_line+1 // current line's default value is 0
    var x = 0;
    var limit = bookcount-1; //bookcount is total number of books

    while(x != 1) {
        request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET","http://example.com/books/?book="+i,true);                    
        request.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
                var jsonbook = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                alert('genre is'+jsonbook.genre);
            }
        }
        request.send()

        if(jsonbook.genre == "scifi"){
            alert('book is at '+i);
            x=1;
        }
        if(i>limit){
            alert('end of book list');
            x=1;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON book is out of scope. Also, the ajax call happens asynchronously (thats the a in ajax) Try it be calling a straight forward function recursivley. sth. like:

```
function check_book(bookID, limit) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://example.com/books/?book=" + bookID, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var jsonbook = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            alert('genre is' + jsonbook.genre);
            if (jsonbook.genre == "scifi") {
                alert('book is at ' + bookID);
                return;
            } else if (bookID > limit) {
                alert('end of book list');
                return,
            } else {
                bookID++;
                check_book(bookID, limit)
            }
        }
    }
    request.send()
}

function find_book(){ // called by button onclick
    var i = curr_line+1 // current line's default value is 0
    var limit = bookcount-1; //bookcount is total number of books

    check_book(i, limit);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First observation. Try moving the below code  under your `alert('genre is'+jsonbook.genre);` line.

```
if(jsonbook.genre == "scifi"){
 alert('book is at '+i);
 x=1;
 }

if(i>limit){
alert('end of book list');
x=1;
}
```

It should look like below as the call is asynchronous once it returns you have to process the jsonobject with your logics

```
   if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
    {

       var jsonbook = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
       alert('genre is'+jsonbook.genre);
       if(jsonbook.genre == "scifi"){
         alert('book is at '+i);
         x=1;
       }

       if(i>limit){
           alert('end of book list');
            x=1;
       }
    }
```

Comment: This still results in calling the function causing a browser crash. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Browser crash is not for this code.. It is because of more memory intensive works.. Something like a big loop